# is it correct to use "completely" at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> I got my ankle completely dislocated.

OR

> I got my ankle dislocated completely.

Is the second sentence grammatically incorrect. If not, then which one should be preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is grammatical and idiomatic.
The second is not idiomatic. It's not a construction that most native English speakers would be likely to use.

There are contexts where you could place **completely** at the end of a sentence. It really depends on the sentence, for example:

> I have completely cleaned the house and tidied the garage.
> This is the usual way of stating things.

> I have cleaned the house and tidied the garage, completely!

Here **completely** is added to the end of the sentence by way of emphasis. In speech it could be an exclamation to underline the extent of your work.

Your second example could work the same way if you indicated a pause after **ankle**.